# jQuery datatable fnRender is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datatables

I'm using jQuery datatable plugin to sort my Datetime column of my table.
I get datetime from database as `07/23/2015 3:45:33 AM`, but I have to display as `23-Jul-15 3:45:33 AM`.

If I format the date column to the required format and try to sort, then it sorts as string, not as datetime. I tried giving `sType: date` also, but no luck.

Finally decided to use `fnRender()` in `aoColumns`. This works fine in Chrome, but not in IE all versions. Unable to figure out the reason.

Code is like below:

```
"aoColumns": [{
    "sWidth": "150px",
    "fnRender": function(oObj) {
        var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        var inputDate = oObj.aData[0];
        var splitsDate = inputDate.split(' ')[0];
        var splits = splitsDate.split('/');
        var splitsTime = inputDate.split(' ')[1] + ' ' + inputDate.split(' ')[2];
        var fDate = ($.trim(splits[1]).length == 1 ? '0' + splits[1] : splits[1]) 
                        + '-' + months[$.trim(splits[0] - 1)] + '-' 
                        + $.trim(splits[2]).substring(2) + ' ' + splitsTime;
        return fDate;
    }
}]
```

Comment: Can you confirm what version of DataTables you're using. And please note that `fnRender()` was deprecated some time ago, and has been removed entirely from current versions of Datatables. See [the Datatables docs](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert).

Comment: I'm using datatable version 1.8.0. As of now, fnRender is removed in newer versions i.e, 1.10. But, even still, this has to work in older versions right? Pls correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Well, yes, it ought to work. But, Datatables 1.8 is quite old: when it was released, the current IE version was IE9, and even that had only just come out. So there cannot be any guarantee that Datatables 1.8 will work with more recent IE versions. It may also have issues with newer jQuery versions, which is also important, because the same applies (even more so) to old versions of jQuery. jQuery contains many lines of code dedicated to resolving issues in specific browser versions, so if you're using a jQuery version of the same age, it won't have any IE10/IE11 fixes, and not many for IE9.

Comment: i'm using jquery/2.2.3 jquery.ui/1.11.4 and datatables/1.10.11